# How to pass agruments (id) to dialog in flutter

Tags: flutter, showdialog

well, my problem is when i use **navigator** i cannot open alert-dialog, **on the same screen** and when i use **showDialog** i dont have my 'book-detail' as argument. please help..

My Code :

```
 leading: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
       // Navigator.of(context)
       //  .pushNamed(BookUpdate.routename, arguments: widget.bookId);

      showDialog(
        context: context,            
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return BookUpdate();
        },
      );
    },
```

Comment: Not sure, but if you called Navigator first, it will launch a new screen,. You can't use dialog like that

Comment: thanks for reply @jitsm555, i commented out the navigator.  it update the book but opens a new screen. i want to open it on the same screen.
my dialog is also working when i add a new book, but problem is when i update the book it shows blank form.

Comment: this code is perfectly clean, there is something wrong with your BookUpdate widget, please paste that code